# Can't upgrade nginx on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: nginx, apt

I'm stuck on nginx version 1.1.19!

Following the instructions here http://www.jeffmould.com/2013/10/19/upgrading-nginx-ubuntu-12-04/ I did:

```
service nginx stop
add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

which output this:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
linux-headers-virtual linux-image-virtual linux-virtual mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server-5.5        mysql-server-core-5.5 nginx-common nginx-light
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
```

And the version is still 1.1.19. I tried rebooting the server, but that did not solve the problem. Is nginx even being upgraded (the held back line suggests it isn't)? If it is, is it being installed in a weird place? Using whereis and locate, I haven't been able to find an nginx binary of the latest version, so it seems like it's just not upgrading at all for some reason.

Some more info that might be relevant: when I run

```
apt-get install nginx
```

It outputs:

```
nginx is already the newest version.
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up fixing it by using apt-get remove, purge, and auto-remove, then reinstalling all the dependencies and running apt-get install nginx after adding the repository like in the question